# Probability solution verification

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

On a statistics trial exam I encountered the following tricky exercise:

Assume that there are two types of car drivers in a country. Safe drivers constitute $70$% of the population and they have a yearly accident probability of $10$%, and unsafe drivers constitute $30$% of the population with a yearly accident probability of $50$%. An insurance company computes the price for risk insurance as follows: 400 times the probability of an accident in the next year.

A new costumer wishes to get a risk insurance, and all that is known is that he had an accident in the previous year. What price should he pay for the insurance?

---

### My solution

I used Bayes theorem and conditional probabilities.

Given is that:

- $P(\text{Accident Last Year} \mid \text{Group 1}) = 0.1$
- $P(\text{ALY} \mid \text{Group 2}) = 0.5$
- $P(\text{Group 1}) = 0.7$
- $P(\text{Group 2}) = 0.3$

By Applying Bayes Theorem we want to check what the probability is that the person is in each of these groups.

So 
$$P(\text{Group 1} \mid \text{ALY}) = \frac{P(\text{ALY} \mid \text{Group 1})P(\text{Group 1})}{P(\text{ALY}\mid\text{Group 2})P(\text{Group 2})+P(\text{ALY}\mid\text{Group 1})P(\text{Group 1})} = \frac{0.1\cdot 0.7}{0.1\cdot 0.7+0.5\cdot 0.3} = \frac{7}{22}$$

and

$$P(\text{Group 2}\mid\text{ALY}) = \frac{P(\text{ALY}\mid\text{Group 2})P(\text{Group 2})}{P(\text{ALY}\mid\text{Group 2})P(\text{Group 2})+P(\text{ALY}\mid\text{Group 1})P(\text{Group 1})} = \frac{15}{22}$$

Where ALY = Accident Last Year.

Hence we get for the total cost: $0.5\cdot\frac{15}{22}\cdot 400 + 0.1 \cdot\frac{7}{22}\cdot 400 = 149$

---

If I did something wrong can someone please give me feedback and correct me :-)

Comment: The reasoning is fine. I did not check for miscalculations.

Answer (score 1):

By probability of $\frac7{22}$ he should pay $0.5\cdot 400=\$200$ and by probability of $\frac5{22}$ he should pay $0.1\cdot 400=\$40$. The expectation of what he should pay is what you've calculated $(\$149)$.